# React+Redux: State undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am playing around with React and Redux and ran into some issues with connect.

```js
const AppConnected = connect((state) => {text: state.text})(App);
```

In the first example, I get the error message `Cannot get 'text' of undefined` whereas the second example runs without problems. What is the reason behind this?

```js
const AppConnected = connect((state) => {
    return {
        text: state.text
    }
})(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning an object in the first example like you think you are. You're defining the body of a function with a label called `text`.

To return an object literal from an arrow you need to wrap it in `()`.

`(state) => ({})`

Labels in JavaScript are used to control the flow of execution. It's not a recommended pattern but works like this:

```
function () {
text: while(someCondition){ // Label
  if (someOtherCondition) {
    continue text;
  }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[**DOCS:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Parenthesize the body to return an object literal expression:**

```
const AppConnected = connect(state => ({text: state.text}))(App);
```